# "Renewal meeting"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests

What do you call a meeting which has the goal to renew the delegates/members of an association/organization/board? *Renewal meeting/re-election meeting*? Or is *assembly* the word I'm looking for?

I just couldn't find the right expression.

Comment: What do you mean by *renew*? Are you suggesting that membership formally expires and the members must sign up again or pay more dues? Or are you suggesting revitalizing the interest of members?

Comment: Membership renewal owing to expiration, revitalization, resign, etc.

Comment: Let's just say an annual general renewal.

Comment: you should hold a meeting to discuss what to call the meeting.

Comment: Precisely: i'm not a native speaker. We have an expression for that and i'm looking for the correct english phrase.

Comment: A meeting whose purpose is to have everyone renew their membership? I've never heard of such a meeting for an American organization. Maybe we have no word for it because we don't have the concept. Memberships are normally renewed by mail or, these days, a web site. We have meetings where we elect officers, but I don't think that's what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meetings that are held to inspire the membership or to increase their commitment are often called *[rallies](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rally?region=uk&q=rally)* or *[revivals](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revival)* (also *revival meeting*).

Meetings that are held for membership status or elections vary in what they are called depending on the periodicity. Many are yearly and are often called *annual meeting*. Sometimes they are called *membership meetings*, especially if the organization works throughout the year through its officers and committees, and the overall membership meets rarely. Alternatives are *general meetings* and *shareholder (stockholder) meetings*.

If the purpose of the meeting is specifically for selection of officers, they may simply be called *election meetings* or *elections*.

Comment: In my case election meeting would be the proper term. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Organisational meetings which deal with elections and other important subjects are usually dubbed [Annual General Meetings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_general_meeting), or AGMs:

> An annual general meeting (commonly abbreviated as AGM, also known as the annual meeting) is a meeting that official bodies, and associations involving the general public (including companies with shareholders), are often required by law (or the constitution, charter, by-laws etc. governing the body) to hold. **An AGM is held every year to elect the board of directors and inform their members of previous and future activities.** It is an opportunity for the shareholders and partners to receive copies of the company's accounts as well as reviewing fiscal information for the past year and asking any questions regarding the directions the business will take in the future.

While it may sound as if only companies conduct AGMs, it has been appropriated for similar use by most structured bodies to represent important meetings held (annually) which require the presence of most of their members. [Extraordinary General Meetings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraordinary_general_meeting) or EGMs also exist.

Comment: I have been a member of several organizations (in the UK), and all have used the term AGM as described in the above answer. There should be a written *constitution* which sets out the terminology and regulations for the conduct of membership, meetings, elections, etc. - that might contain your answer.